# PBKDF2 for identifier hashing (not password) in .Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, encryption, hash, .net-core

I need to hash identifiers before storing in a database. There will be up to 1 million values overall.  I need to pseudonymise these values to comply with GDPR.

I am using .Net core and I want to stay with the core hashing functionality. I dont want to risk using external hashing implementations. The intention is to add a salt phrase to each value before hashing. These values have already been hashed by the supplier but I will be hashing again before storing in db.

I was going to use SHA256 but I have read that PBKDF2 is more secure. However, I have read that PBKDF2 is prone to collisions. It is of the utmost importance that the hashing implementation I use has a low collision chance. Has PBKDF2 a higher collision rate than simple SHA256? Does using a key-derivation of HMACSHA512 with PBKDF2 as opposed to HMACSHA1 reduce the possibility of collisions?
Would like recommendations for a secure, low-collision one-way hash for Net core.

Comment: Where have you read about PBKDF2 is prone to collisions? It shouldn't be. PBKDF2 has hash function as its parameter. If you use SHA256 as parameter for PBKDF2 it should be more collisions prone than single SHA256.

Comment: "It’s trivial to find colliding passwords when hashing with PBKDF2-HMAC-anything." 
  https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/pbkdf2-hmac

Comment: Ok, I understand now. It is easy to generate collision for specific case. But in practice this will not happen. They used the same salt (which is obviously security flaw), and they used specific message which is equal to hash of some data. Probability of this scenario is equal to 2^(hash size). You can use PBKDF2 with no concerns, just don't forget to use random salt.

Comment: Ah, well.. the salt will stay the same. I will be hashing identifiers using the same salt. these will be batched datasets and it will be important to be able to track the same hash for longitudinal analysis. And when you say  "If you use SHA256 as parameter for PBKDF2 it should be more collisions prone than single SHA256" do you mean I should just use sha256 and not PBKDF2 if i want to reduce the potential for collisions?

Comment: I think PBKDF2 is not needed for your use case. But you should better describe the use case to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There will be up to 1 million values overall. I need to pseudonymise these values to comply with GDPR 
>    I was going to use SHA256 but I have read that PBKDF2 is more secure.

For this use case a proper cryptographic hash is imho the best option.

PBKDF2 is a key derivation function intended to derive higher entropy keys from relatively weak passwords. It uses a hash under the hood so if the hash has certain hash collision probability , pbkdf will have the same.

pbkdf2 is intended to be slow (using iterations) to mitigate feasibility of brute-forcing the input password. You don't need that property, even it may be bad for your use case.

So -you can boldly use sha256 to anonymize your data, imho it may be the best option you have today. Indeed principially you cannot prevent the hash collision, but the probability should be negligible